# How do I show two inputs are the same or not

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to just compare two user inputs but I can't seem to get it working and constantly get parse errors. Any help will be appreciated.

```
main = do  
foo <- putStrLn "Enter two numbers."  
numone <- getLine
numtwo <- getLine  
putStrLn $ ("You entered " ++ numone ++ " and " ++ numtwo) 

if 
    numone == numtwo 
    then 
        putStrLn "They are the same"
          else
             putStrLn "They are not the same"
```

Comment: Please rewrite the title to something more descriptive.

Comment: If you get errors, it'd be helpful if you paste them in your question. If it runs but does the wrong thing, you should ideally say what input you gave, what you expected it to do, and what actually happened instead.

Comment: I am getting errors that say 'error: parse error on input 'if' '

Comment: works fine for me. How are you running or compiling it? Is this code _exactly_ what you have locally?

Comment: @SimonShine  sorry, but your edit must be rolled back. the whole point to the question was its wrong indentation. if we fix that, the question loses its meaning.

Comment: @WillNess: I'm sorry, and thank you for rolling it back. I realized this only after having read your answer and couldn't figure out how.

Comment: @SimonShine the wonders of menu-based interfaces... :)

Answer (score 8):

The errors probably arise through to small changes in indentation between the local version, and the one posted here. Indentation in Haskell is quite important, since the compiler uses it to understand where certain "blocks" begin and end.

Furthermore you can remove the `foo <-` part (well this is not wrong, but quite useless). So after reformatting we get:

```
main = do  
  putStrLn "Enter two numbers."  
  numone <- getLine
  numtwo <- getLine  
  putStrLn $ ("You entered " ++ numone ++ " and " ++ numtwo) 
  if numone == numtwo 
  then 
    putStrLn "They are the same"
  else
    putStrLn "They are not the same"
```

Furthermore now you compare two strings. You can convert these to `Int`s (or other readable types) with for example [**`readLn :: Read a => IO a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readLn):

```
main = do  
  putStrLn "Enter two numbers."  
  numone <- readLn :: IO Int
  numtwo <- readLn :: IO Int
  putStrLn $ ("You entered " ++ show numone ++ " and " ++ show numtwo) 
  if numone == numtwo 
  then 
    putStrLn "They are the same"
  else
    putStrLn "They are not the same"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed tabs and spaces in your code snippet, and the blank line in between your print and your `if` expression is indented by less than the other lines are. Your whole do-block must have the same initial indentation. I suggest using only spaces (or only tabs, if you prefer) so that it's harder to accidentally wind up with misaligned code that looks correctly aligned.

---

I see I answered on the basis of code OP never wrote, because of an incorrect edit someone else made. It "fixed" the indentation but was actually still wrong for a different reason. Oh well, it's still an indentation problem but not one to do with mixing spaces and tabs.

Comment: using explicit braces { ; } would make it work anyway. why are they so unpopular? I really don't understand this. I would even make it a requirement to always use them.

Comment: I can understand wanting to use `{;}` for do blocks, but for most other kinds of blocks I think things get rather messy and unpleasant without the layout rule. You really want to write `f a = let {x = 1; y = 2} in x + y + g a where {g 0 = 1; g n = n * 2}`?

Comment: if the other alternative is a brittle code, yes. if the use of a smart editor with clear cues about indentation is mandatory, maybe then it's not needed. and braces come nicely together with proper indentation, just that the code doesn't break from an occasional tab or extra space, just becomes ugly.

Comment: @amalloy: I'm the one who made the edit; sorry for that!

Comment: actually, the original code had the same problem of mixing spaces and tabs. this can be seen by clicking on "source" in the first entry in the question's edit history. so your answer was perfectly on point. :)